# Git merge finds conflict after reverting to common version between branches

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-revert

I have two branches called `test` and `prod-candidate`. These two branches have a common commit in their history, `a0e378cfe28`, which was originally in the test branch and was later merged into prod-candidate. After this commit, the two branches went different ways and had other commits associated to them.

It is now time to merge test into prod-candidate again, so I was hoping that by reverting all the commits in the prod-candidate branch back to commit `a0e378cfe28` I would be able to do the merge without problems. I did the revert and by running `git diff` I was able to verify that the revert was successful because the prod-candidate branch has the exact same contents as commit `a0e378cfe28`.

Unfortunately, after checking out prod-candidate and running `git merge test`, I am getting a conflict in the POM file and I can't understand why. The test branch has a POM with version `18.4.0-101`, and prod-candidate, which before the revert had version `18.3.0-204`, currently has version `18.3.0-101` (which is the same as commit `a0e378cfe28`).

Why can't I merge the branches after reverting to a common base commit?

Comment: What do you mean by "I was hoping that by reverting all the commits in the prod-candidate branch back to commit a0e378cfe28"? What exact command did you execute?

Comment: Note that "the exact same contents" does not imply that the history to get there is the same. The history of changes is more important to git than the final result of the accumulation of all of the changes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I reverted every single commit in the prod-candidate branch all the way down to a0e378cfe28. This way, the prod-candidate branch was at a state that the test branch once was, and therefore I expected to be able to merge test into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing this the hard way. If you want the `prod-candidate` branch to contain the same changes as the `test` branch, the easiest way is to do this:

```
git checkout prod-candidate
git reset --hard test
```

This will effectively move `prod-candidate` to point at the same commit as `test`. This means that it will have the exact same revision history. You won't have any merge conflicts to worry about, either.

**Note**

`git revert` will create a new commit that reverses the changes of the specified commit. If you revert multiple commits, one at a time, the end result is a chain of commits that undoes the changes in the previous commits. Even though you end up with the same content on both branches, they have two different histories. You are getting merge conflicts because a line was changed in different ways on both branches. Git does not detect that the line of code in `prod-candidate` has been changed back to the same content as the shared parent commit.

Comment: Unfortunately a hard reset is not an option because non-FF pushes aren't allowed in the repo. As for the multiple commits, I'm actually using `--no-commit` with my revert and I'm pretty satisified with the result. I guess "a line was changed in different ways on both branches" is the best explanation so far to the problem I'm having. One workaround is to add `-X theirs` to the merge which will force the conflict to be resolved on the side of `test` instead of `prod-candidate`.

Comment: @Phil yes, due to the constraints you will have to deal with the merge conflicts. Sounds like you have a good way to do that.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but can you add the `-X theirs` option below in case forced pushes aren't allowed? I think many repositories have that option configured... Just to make the answer more complete. Thanks!